# how to integrate InMobi in cocos2d game?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ads, inmobi

Can i integrate InMobi in cocos2d game? I integrated InMobi in UI Game but i don't know how to integrate the InMobi in cocos2d game? Any one tell me if any tutorials.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I work for InMobi.  All of our iOS tutorials are available at 
http://developer.inmobi.com/wiki/index.php?title=InMobi_SDK_3.7_for_iOS

There shouldn't be any problems integrating with Cocos2D